# Multiline Message Hangouts Chat Chatbot

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm newbie in developing Hangouts Chat Chatbots. I have a question if there's guide on how to create multi message on onmessage function from google script?
example:

> Bot: Insert Number 1
>
> User: 5
>
> Bot Insert Number 2
>
> User: 5
>
> Bot: The Answer is 5

Comment: Please refer [Cards](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards) in Chat

Comment: [tag:hangouts-api] refers to a Google+ Hangouts API. It is now deprecated.